# Negligible Set in Uncountably Infinite Space

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

When dealing with infinite probability space, the probability of any particular outcome is zero. Why is this true in the uncountably infinite probability space?

An example is a Lebesgue measure on [0,1].  Why is $\mathbb{L}[a,b]=0$ for $b=a$? Is this what the author means?

Reference:
Shreve, Steven E. $\textit{Stochastic Calculus for Finance II : Continuous-Time Models}$. Springer, 2008.

Comment: What do you mean by "why"? It's counterintuitive, but true. Zero doesn't mean impossible, but implausible to the highest degree (if that makes sense).

Comment: The first sentence is not true, and in fact for a *countably* infinite probability space there always exists an outcome with positive probability. It *is* true that for Lebesgue measure the measure of any singleton is $0$, and that is probably what the author meant. This is a very roundabout method of proving the uncountability of the reals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not at all true. Consider the real line with Borel sigma algebra and the measure $\mu$ defined by $\mu(E)=1$ if $0 \in E$ and $0$ otherwise. Then $\mu \{0\} >0$.

Comment: True, but it might be helpful to also address OP's concern about things being possible despite having $0$ possibility of occuring.